# Parallel.ForEach how to check process?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I'm using  `Parallel.ForEach` for a large set of jobs.

I want to know how does the process go.

So currently I wrote:

```
int processCnt=0;
Parallel.ForEach(allJobs, myPallOption, (oneJob) =>
    {
      processCnt++;
      Console.WriteLine("Job#"+processCnt+"/"+totalCnt);
      doJob(oneJob);
    }
```

But I think  `processCnt++;` will be locked somehow and this may not be a good idea.
This could slow down the process.

So is there any better way to know how many jobs are already completed?

**I don't really care about the accuracy of the `processCnt`,
I just want a higher speed. I think `processCnt++` may have slower performance.**

Answer (score 0):

How about doing:

```
int processCnt=0;
Parallel.ForEach(allJobs, myPallOption, (oneJob) =>
    {
      var currentCount = Interlocked.Increment(ref processCnt);
      Console.WriteLine("Job#"+currentCount+"/"+totalCnt);
      doJob(oneJob);
    }
```

By having a local variable 'currentCount' you are sure that 'processCnt' will not be changed between your local increment and writing it to console.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `processCnt++;` with `Interlocked.Increment(ref processCnt);`

You don't need to assign the result to another variable because of using [ref].

Answer (score 0):

To specifically adress your question: the ++ operator is not designed to be threadsafe, so there is no extra cost. It will produce wrong results though. Interlocked.Increment (as suggested in the other answers) is better, it is correct, and if it is still not very expensive. Way cheaper than an actual lock.

Interlocked.Increment is cheap because it can be implemented using a special CPU instruction that freezes all other cores for the time of that instruction.

Comment: Will the downvoter explain what I said wrong?